# Finding diagonal matrix D and invertible matrix C such that $A=C^{-1}DC$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Here is the full question:

Consider the matrix:
\begin{equation*}
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 5  \\
-2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Find a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $C$ such that $A =CDC^{-1}$. Deduce $A^3$. Do not find $C$. Make some conclusions.

My question is how am I supposed to find $D$ without finding C knowing that $D=C^{-1}AC$. 
If I could use $C$ then I would find the eigenvectors of $A$ to get C but the question says I shouldn't find it.

Comment: I don’t understand this problem statement. It says “Find ... an invertible matrix $C$... Do not find $C$.” Which is it? Are you sure that you’ve transcribed the problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you’re meant to diagonalize $A$ explicitly (the problem statement as you have it in your question says both “Find $C$” and “Do not find $C$;” I have no idea what to make of that), in order to find $D$ you can’t get around computing eigenvalues of $A$.

However, it’s possible to compute $A^3$ without going even that far by applying the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Let the characteristic polynomial of $A$ be $p(x)$. Then we can divide $x^3$ by this polynomial to get $x^3=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$. Since $p(A)=0$, we then have $A^3=r(A)$, which, since $p$ is quadratic, will be of the form $aI+bA$. So, you just need to compute the characteristic polynomial and find the remainder when you divide $x^3$ by it.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Find the eigenvalues and vectors.
Step 2: What is D? (what is C as a consequence)?
Step 3: If $A = CDC^{-1}$, what happens when you do $A^2$? $A^3$?

Comment: What is $D$ other than $^{−1}$?

Comment: D is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. (and 0 otherwise)

Comment: Thank you, my bad

Answer (score 2):

This is an eigenvalue decomposition problem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix). 
$$\bf A v = \lambda v $$
where $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue, and $v$ an eigenvector. Then 
$$\bf A C = DC $$
Where C is a matrix made of eigenvectors, and D is a diagonal matrix whose diagonals are the eigenvalues of $\bf A$. Then 
$$\bf A = C D C^{-1}$$

Then it’s quite easy to find $A^3$.

Comment: How how to do it without having $C$? $A^{2}=CDC^{-1}CDC^{-1}=CD^2C^{-1}$, we still need C here.

Comment: @Sergio If you know how to find the eigenvalues, then you don’t need to know $\bf C$ to make any deductions about $\bf A^3$. In fact $\bf A^3 = C D^3 C^{-1}$. And $\bf D^3$ is still diagonal.

Comment: Yes but for getting its values, we still need C, what's $A^3$ here as an example?

Comment: Your question says do not find $\bf C$, so I'm assuming you need an expression of $\bf A^3$in terms of $\bf C$ and $\bf D$, and not its values.